# Resolution is strange on second animation via template

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

In my Universal Windows 10 app, I have an animation that shrinks a custom control whose looks is applied via a template. It works as expected the first time it is run. The second time it is run, the start of the animation is rendered in a horrible resolution, apparently tainted by the previous run:

[image: First time on the left, second time on the right]

First time is on the left; second time on the right.

If, instead of using a custom control with a template, I hardcode everything in XAML, the problem doesn't occur.

If I grow rather than shrink the target, the problem doesn't occur.

Let me start with the non-templated version, which is shorter and easier to read than the templated version:

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AnimationStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Show">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="transform"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                            To="0.1"
                            BeginTime="0:00:2"
                            Duration="0:00:1">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="transform"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                            To="0.1"
                            BeginTime="0:00:2"
                            Duration="0:00:1">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Hide" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="16"
            FontSize="122"
            Text="Q">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="transform" />
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="16"
            Content="Animate!"
            Click="OnAnimateClicked" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The code-behind is as follows:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnAnimateClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Hide", useTransitions: false);
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Show", useTransitions: true);
    }
}
```

This works fine every time. But. Instead of applying the `ScaleTransform` to the `TextBlock`'s `RenderTransform` directly, I have a custom control with a template applied. For illustration purposes we can use a custom control that is little more than a placeholder:

```
public sealed class CustomControl : Control
{
}
```

Then change the XAML to replace the `TextBlock` with a `CustomControl`, applying a template to the `CustomControl`:

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="local:CustomControl">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomControl">
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="Q" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AnimationStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Show">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="transform"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                            To="0.1"
                            BeginTime="0:00:2"
                            Duration="0:00:1">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="transform"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                            To="0.1"
                            BeginTime="0:00:2"
                            Duration="0:00:1">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Hide" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:CustomControl
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="16"
            FontSize="122">
            <local:CustomControl.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="transform" />
            </local:CustomControl.RenderTransform>
        </local:CustomControl>
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="16"
            Content="Animate!"
            Click="OnAnimateClicked"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The first time I click the *Animate* button, this works exactly like the first version. The second and subsequent times, the initial animation rendering uses the really coarse resolution shown on the right:

[image: First time on the left, second time on the right]

The coarseness seems to be proportional to the shrinkage factor. Is this a bug of some sort (a failed optimization?), or is my understanding of templates flawed?

Comment: Just for giggles and deduction, have you tried hard setting your FontSize on the inner TextBlock so it's not left to the system scaling prefs?

Comment: I hadn't tried that. But now I have, and the behavior remains the same.

Comment: Since I know I'm going to end up running into this also I'll try to dink with your example later. Nothing really stands out except there's no RenderTransformOrigin set on your control, but I wouldn't expect that to matter in this instance. Makes me wonder if the aliasing is occurring on the actual font. Good question!

Comment: Heh. Good luck! (The real-life code which I distilled down to a more-or-less stand-alone repro _does_ set an origin, so the problem lies elsewhere.)